# Adding a new js file to my lambda function using Serverless

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create an API on AWS Lambda, and using Serverless framework for deployment.

I'm a complete noob at it, so I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing. So here's the old favorite, hello world (index.js):

```
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Promise = require('promise');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!')
})
```

That works fine as is. But when I add the following:

```
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const Register = require('./controller/registryController');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.get('/createUserName', function (req, res) {
    var prom = Register.createUser();
    prom.then((message) => {
        res.status(201).json(message);
    })
    .catch((message) => {
        res.status(400).json(message);
    });
})

module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

I get:

> "Cannot find module './controller/registryController'"

Which is strange, cause the file is right there, when I look in lambda. Here's its contents:

```
const dbConnMysql = require('./dbMngrMysql');

var methods = {
    createUser: function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let connection = dbConnMysql.createConnection();
            dbConnMysql.startConnection(connection)
            .then((fulfilled) => {
                let table = 'userNamePool';
                return dbConnMysql.selectFrom(connection, table, null);
            })
            .then((fulfilled) => {
                return dbConnMysql.closeConnection(connection).then(function() {
                    let result = fulfilled;
                    let response = {
                        "statusCode": 200,
                        "headers": {"my_header": "my_value"},
                        "body": JSON.stringify(result),
                        "isBase64Encoded": false
                    };

                    resolve(response);
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                let response = {
                    "statusCode": 404,
                    "headers": {"my_header": "my_value"},
                    "body": JSON.stringify(error),
                    "isBase64Encoded": false
                };

                resolve(response);
            });
        });
    }
};

module.exports = methods;
```

Here's the project structure / directory:

[image]

And here's my serverless.yml for good measure:

service: sample-api

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: yapyap
  deploymentBucket: yadayada
  role: blahblahblah

functions:
  app:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
  createUserName:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http: 'GET /createUserName'
```

What am I doing wrong? Anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Can you show your file structure too?

Comment: Is it just a typo? `controller` instead of `controllers`?

Comment: I see your folder name is `controllers`, yet, you require from `controller`

Comment: Oh wow, that... completely slipped. Thank you for that. Could you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo:

`controller` instead of `controllers`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't comment because of the reputation restriction.

The problem may be because you haven't created *controller* folder.

To create it properly
create a folder. Name it *controller*. Create your *registryController.js* and put your code in it.
now you will be able to call it as

```
const Register = require('./controller/registryController');
```

Also on a side note, if you want to use a serverless architecture, separate your server side and client side code completely. Put your HTML files and client-side scripts in an S3 bucket. put your server-side code in lambda function and connect it with API Gateway. then use a JavaScript function to call the API. Keep server-side calls as less as possible.